# C# Post Increment

Tags: c#, post-increment

While I am testing post increment operator in a simple console application, I realized that I did not understand full concept. It seems weird to me:

```
int i = 0;
bool b = i++ == i;
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

The output has been false. I have expected that it would be true. AFAIK, at line 2, because of the post increment, compiler does comparison and assigned b to true, after i incremented by one. But obviously I am wrong.
After that I modify the code like that:

```
int i = 0;
bool b = i == i++;
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

This time output has been true. What did change from first sample?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose `i` has the value `0` initially, as it does in your examples.

`i++ == i` reads `i` (`0`), increments `i`, reads `i` again (`1`), and compares the two values: `0 == 1`.

`i == i++` reads `i` (`0`), reads `i` again (`0`), increments `i`, and compares the two values: `0 == 0`.

The increment happens *immediately* after reading the old value.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to your first snippet of code:

Here, `bool b = i++ == i;`is `0 == 1`and this is because as you know `i++` is a post increment so `i` remains `0` at `i++` but after that part is finished executing and it is being compared to the right hand side which is `i` , by this time the value has change to 1 due to that previous post increment. This is why you are getting `False` when doing : `bool b = i++ == i;`.

Like @hvd said: *The increment happens immediately after reading the old value*.

Comment: In the second case `bool b = i == i++;` i.e. 0 == 0 which is true  and then increment happens. like first the value is compared and then i is incremented But in first case it is happening other way round like `bool b = i++ == i;` i.e. 0 == 1 it first read 0 then increment i and then compare it by that time i is incremented to 1 that is why he is getting false.

Comment: That is correct.The second snippet of code is self-understandable if you understand the concept behind the first part.It's the same in most programming languages.It's a fundamental basic concept.

Answer (score 1):

The order of evaluation of the postfix and the equality operator is from left to right, so the code behaves as explained in the code comments.

```
int i = 0;
bool b = i++ == i;
// 1.) i++ returns old value i.e. 0
// 2.) but after that it increments and becomes 1
// 3.) hence, bool b = 0 == 1; --> evaluates to false
Console.WriteLine(b); // prints false

int i = 0;
bool b = i == i++;
// 1.) i returns old value i.e. 0
// 2.) i++ returns old value i.e. 0, as this is the end of the statement after that it would increment
// 3.) hence, bool b = 0 == 0; --> evaluates to true
Console.WriteLine(b); // prints true
```